# extracting column from matrix

Tags: matrix, python-3.x, user-defined-functions, extract

Alright so I was just wondering how I would extract a column from a matrix. This would be using a user defined in function.

so for example:

```
D = [[2,9], [5,2], [1,0]]
def col(B,j):


print(col(D,0))
```

would result in:
    [2,5,1]

EDIT: nevermind figured it out myself

```
def col(B,j):
    Z=[]
    for i in range(len(B)):
        Z.append(B[i][j])

    return Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def col(B,j):
    Z=[]
    for i in range(len(B)):
        Z.append(B[i][j])
    return Z
```

Comment: No need for `range`: `return [row[j] for row in B]`