# Extracting a column from a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I would like to extract the first column from a numpy matrix,

```
a = matrix
([[3, 2, 4, 6]
  [4, 5, 6, 5]
  [6, 4, 5, 3]
  [3, 5, 6, 7]])
```

and extract the first column as

```
a_column = [3,4,6,3]
```

I tried implementing [extracting column from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696217/extracting-column-from-matrix)
however it did not work and gave the same matrix which I used as input as the output

Comment: What is matrix? numpy.matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is the best library if you're dealing with matrices

```
import numpy as np
k = [[3, 2, 4, 6],
  [4, 5, 6, 5],
  [6, 4, 5, 3],
  [3, 5, 6, 7]]
k = np.array(k)
print(k[:,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index the first item in each list with a comprehension. Also, use `numpy` to handle arrays.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
  [3, 2, 4, 6]
  [4, 5, 6, 5]
  [6, 4, 5, 3]
  [3, 5, 6, 7]
])

column_a = [x[0] for x in a]
```